# Horizontal scrolling on mouse wheel not working with RecyclerView Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling

I have taken a horizontal RecyclerView to avail the horizontal scrolling in my app, but when I am trying scroll using mouse wheel its not scrolling rather clicking on the items according to the cursor position.Scrolling works when I move my mouse and use the mouse wheel at the same time otherwise it doesn't.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/apps_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"                        
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/layout_horizontal_apps_next"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="8"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/layout_horizontal_apps_back"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

**apps_horizontal_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/horizontal_app_background">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_icon_apps_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 adapterHorizontalApps = new HorizontalAppsAdapter(categorizedApp);
 layoutManagerHorizontalApps = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
 recyclerViewHorizontalApps = findViewById(R.id.apps_horizontal);
 recyclerViewHorizontalApps.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerHorizontalApps);
 recyclerViewHorizontalApps.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
 recyclerViewHorizontalApps.setAdapter(adapterHorizontalApps);
```

Answer (score 0):

it will never working horizontal scroll will move with mouse cursor mouse wheel only works with vertical scroll

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this myself but you might be able to make it work by adding a onGenericMotionEvent() listener to the RecyclerView. You could then use the vertical scroll offset you get from the mouse scroll to manually trigger a horizontal scroll offset change.

It would look something like this:

```
recyclerView.setOnGenericMotionListener((OnGenericMotionListener) (view, event) -> {
    if (event.isFromSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER)) {
         switch (event.getAction()) {
             case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
                 float verticalScrollOffset = event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_VSCROLL);
                 float scrollOffset = verticalScrollOffset * 100.f; // Modify this to a custom multiplier. 
                 recyclerView.scrollToPosition(scrollOffset)
                 return true;
         }
     }
    return super.onGenericMotionEvent(event);
});
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onGenericMotionEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)